# No second display over HDMI (16.04 LTS) hybrid graphics

Tags: drivers, graphics, 16.04, hdmi, amd-graphics

I cannot seem to enable or use my HDMI port in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. As I connect it with my TV, there's no signal on either ends. Detecting displays doesn't work.

It probably has something to do with the fact that my Lenovo uses a power-saving Intel GPU as default and a display controller ATI Radeon R7. Which one has the HDMI on it?

Can this be activated somehow? 14.04 LTS worked automatically.

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500 (rev 09)

04:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Venus XTX [Radeon HD 8890M / R9 M275X/M375X] (rev ff)
```

Cheers,